# Solr Replication Master Slave - ReplicateAfter attribute

Tags: solr, replication

I am new to the Master/Slave configuration in Solr and am trying to understand what the replicateAfter attribute in the master slave configuration of solr means.  I initially thought that after a commit/optimize, the master would send the updates to all the slaves.  But it doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is the request handler configuration for replicate.

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
  <lst name="master">
    <str name="enable">${enable.master:false}</str>
    <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
    <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
     <str name="replicateAfter">optimize</str>
    <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt</str>
 </lst>
 <lst name="slave">
    <str name="enable">${enable.slave:false}</str>
    <str name="masterUrl">http://${MASTER_CORE_URL}/${solr.master.core.name}/replication</str>
    <str name="pollInterval">${POLL_TIME}</str>
 </lst>
```

The slave seems to get the updates after the poll Interval.  But my requirement is to have the indexes of slaves updated immediately after a commit/optimize to the Master.   Can the Master communicate to the slaves on a commit/optimize?  Or is the communication only one way from the slave to the Master?  Can someone please help answer these questions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, Here is the Answer.  ReplicateAfter tells Master when to make new versions of index available for when slaves asks for updates (Thanks to raticulin for answering it!)

Answer (score 2):

Slaves poll the master continuously, master does non initiate any communication with slaves. You should just lower ${POLL_TIME} enough so replication will  happen very fast after commit on master.

Comment: Hmmm.... Are there any other alternatives?  Wouldn't changing the poll time to a lower value, keep the master busy with the poll requests from the slaves (every second or every couple of seconds?).   What does "ReplicateAfter" attribute do?

Comment: that is not a search request, will not cost much. ReplicateAfter tells Master when to make new versions of index available for when slaves asks for updates

Comment: Okay, Sounds good.  I will try that.  Thanks for the information about the ReplicateAfter attribute.